# How to Refresh GridView after closing down Dialog in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a main page with a Gridview that shows data from a Database. In the gridview there is a button, when this button is clicked a Dialog will appear allowing u to edit the selected row. The dialog is created as an aspx class. When i edit the data and close down the dialog i want to refresh my GridView on the Main page so the edited data is represented. How can i do this?

my code for editing the data and closing down the dialog is this:

```
 protected void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string alias = Request.QueryString["alias"];
            string custid = Request.QueryString["custid"];
            controller.EditDeliveries(custid, alias, tdaysField.Text, thoursField.Text, ttypeField.Text, pdaysField.Text, phoursField.Text, ptypeField.Text);
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "onUpload", "<script type='text/javascript'> window.close();</script>");
        }
```

Can anyone help ?
And if u need to see more code please tell me.

Comment: Is your page that contains grid view be refreshed after closing the dialog box?

Comment: no my control is not on the dialog its on the main page. so i have to get hold of the main page gridview somehow and then update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your datasource again and rebind it in the postback

```
   gvMyGrid.DataSource = myData; //Fresh from the database
   gvMyGrid.DataBind();          //Bam, fresh data
```

Edit: Oh and if it's another Control that is the source of the postback, you can use a Bubble Event to trigger the refresh.

Second Edit: To have the Dialog Page tell the Main Page to update that grid:

```
    RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CommandEventArgs("DataUpdated", "This could be null, or I could be a message to let the user know things are updated"));
```

Then on your main Page

```
   protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (e is CommandEventArgs)
        {
            var args = (CommandEventArgs)e;
            //Could use args.CommandArgument here
            switch(args.CommandName)
            {
                  case "DataUpdated":

                     gvMyGrid.DataSource = myData; 
                     gvMyGrid.DataBind();          
                     return true;                  //Handled the event LIKE A BOSS
            }
        }
        return false;                              //I didn't handle this event
    }
```

Comment: It was not the binding and refreshing i was looking for but how to get the GridView in the main window to refresh after closing the dialog. I cant refresh the MainPage.Gridview1 from DialogPage :)

Comment: Ah, you want a bubble event, one moment

Comment: i insert this line of code `RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CommandEventArgs("DataUpdated", "This could be null, or I could be a message to let the user know things are updated"));` efter closing the dialog ?

Comment: @Lahib Yeah, that'd be the perfect time, but make it RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CommandEventArgs("DataUpdated", null));

Comment: @MikeyMouse Well i did this and im debuging the app. And after closing the dialog. the code deosnt rute back to the main page.. it just runs out the method for the button click (As shown in question) and then in asp code and thats it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21326/discussion-between-mikey-mouse-and-lahib)